# Extension method for precisely two different types

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I'm using the code below. It's designed for a certain type to limit it's popup-ness in intellisense etc.

```
public static Generic Get<Generic>(this Entity input)
{
  return (Generic)input;
}
```

Now I'd like to use the same *Get* method for another type (or, to be fully covered, a few another types but still a fix number of). So I added a second method and the code looks as follows.

```
public static Generic Get<Generic>(this Entity input)
{
  return (Generic)input;
}

public static Generic Get<Generic>(this Entity2 input)
{
  return (Generic)input;
}
```

It strikes me that a better approach would be to keep it in the same method body and still cover all the regarded types. Is there a syntax for including e.g. two different types in the signature? Something like this **pseudo-code** below.

```
public static Generic Get<Generic>(this [Entity, Entity2] input)
{
  return (Generic)input;
}
```

The best approach I can think of, as shown below, consists of a entry method for each type and the logic in a private place. It makes sense when the logic is extensive but looks kind of superfluous when it's only a line or two.

```
public static Generic Get<Generic>(this Entity input)
{
  return CommonLogic(input);
}

public static Generic Get<Generic>(this Entity2 input)
{
  return CommonLogic(input);
}

private static Generic CommonLogic(Object input)
{
  return (Generic)input;
}
```

Comment: I would go with the last approach for sure, or put it on the object?

Comment: is there anything in common between `Entity` and `Entity2`?

Comment: Do you control the source of the EntityX classes? If so, you could create a marker (empty) interface and have only those classes implement the interface. Then have the 'this' extension method parameter type be of that interface.

Comment: Please use `T` rather than `Generic` in your code. Such a simple change will make your code an order of magnitude faster to read!

Comment: @Dennis_E Can't you do something like `where T : Entity, Entity2`

Comment: @user469104 If they do that, what properties / methods do you suggest they interact with in the extension method, since they are now talking to an empty interface?

Comment: @LuckyLikey I deleted my comment, but no, you can't do that. `where T : Entity, Entity2` means T must implement Entity AND Entity2, not Entity OR Entity2. You cannot inherit multiple classes, only interfaces.

Comment: @Dennis_E found that when trying it out :) Check my Answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C# doesn't support the `[Entity, Entity2]` notation, so that option is out.

If `Entity` and `Entity2` share a common interface or base class, then declare it as:

```
public static Generic Get<Generic>(this IEntityCommon input)
{
    return (Generic)input;
}
```

If not and you have created `Entity`, `Entity2` etc, then add a common interface. This interface need not define any methods and can be empty, it simply provides a common type for the extension method.

Failing all that, the "CommonLogic" way is your best option.

Comment: The notation was just a pseudo-code to shorten the explanation. The classes share no common interface dedicated to them only and since the logic is very short, I guess there's no point making the effort to do things right. However, it's good to know in a general case.

Answer (score 3):

you could be doing something like that

```
    public static TSearch Get<TSource, TSearch>(this TSource obj) where TSource : BaseType, ISomeInterface
    {

    }
```

T can now only be of type `BaseType` and implementing `ISomeInterface`, but this would not make it aviable to be restricted to a fix count of supported classes

**EDIT:**

you now can use this on objects of Type `BaseType` implementing `ISomeInterface` and Return the Requested Type `TSearch`. However, you could also just use `where TSource : ISomeInterface`. The clue is that your `Entity`classes implement this interface.

Check [where - generic type constratint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx) to understand how to use it.

Comment: For this to work you'd need two generic types.  The input and the output.  Right now this takes something of a certain type and returns that same type, which is not what the OPs code does.

Comment: @juharr it should now fit (If his `Entity` Classes are typeof `BaseType` and `ISomeInterface`)

Comment: You have to specify `TSource` as a generic type on the method `public static TSearch Get<TSource, TSearch>(this TSource obj)`

Comment: @CarbineCoder Actually as it is now it wouldn't even compile as it would not be able to resolve what `TSource` is.

Comment: @juarr Lol I just re-read and deleted my comment, darn you caught it before i did